# Why are the edges visible when rendering?

Tags: rendering

I feel like this has a simple as hell solution. Trying to follow this tutorial https://youtu.be/JYBPXTful2g on YouTube, and, as badly textured as my character may be, I finished it.

But...

Why are my edges showing when I render the character?

[image]

Comment: Figured it out: 

I had to hide a layer in Photoshop that had the edges still visible (from when I was painting the UVs). The guy actually did that in the tutorial, but it was so fast that I couldn't see what he had done. 

And that's it. Hope it helps!

Comment: Please convert your comment into an answer and add some details about what setup did you have and what actions you made to solve the problem. This could help future seekers with similar problem. Thanks!